# What are ways to show phone conversations?

Tags: video

Suppose you have person A in one room, placing a phone call to person B in another room. How would you show the resulting phone conversation?

I can think of two ways: One is to split the screen, so person A is shown on the left side, and person B on the right side.

The other way, is to have alternating "full shots" switching back and forth between persons A and B.

What are these video techniques called? Are there other techniques that I've overlooked?

Comment: The technique of intercutting two scenes in different locations is called 'Parallel Editing'. http://is.gd/C9x55l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to think of alternate ways to do things, so here are a few.

1. One variation of the split screen is a picture-in-picture layout, where Caller B is in a small (often rectangular) box overlaid on the main shot of Caller A.
2. Another variation of the split screen is a "cloudy" picture-in-picture, where Caller B appears as a cloud-shaped image with fuzzy edges overlaid on the main shot of Caller A, usually floating above Caller A's head. This is sometimes used to make it look as though Person A is thinking of Person B, but I'm pretty sure I've seen it as a phone call too.
3. If the call occurs in present day, a video call on a computer screen can show Caller A and Caller B in a variety of layouts.  It could even include Callers C, D, E, etc.
4. Some scenes only show Caller A, and Caller B is heard without being seen.
5. In the movie The Player, there is a creepy scene in which Tim Robbins calls a woman he's attracted to / stalking.  He's on his cell phone, outside of her house, at night. She can't see him but he is looking in through her windows while they talk. So there are some 2-shots that show both of them on the phone simultaneously. (It's briefly included in [the trailer](http://youtu.be/JdnKpF9fq78?t=1m10s) at 1:10.)